# Counting repeated data

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I'm trying to get maximum repeat of integer in table I tried many ways but could not make it work. The result I'm looking for is as:

`"james";"108"`

As this 108  when I concat of two fields loca+locb repeated two times but others did not I try below sqlfiddle link with sample table structure and the query I tried... [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/76d9f/3)

Query I tried is :

```
select * from (
select name,CONCAT(loca,locb),loca,locb 
, row_number() over (partition by CONCAT(loca,locb) order by CONCAT(loca,locb) ) as att

from Table1 
) tt
where att=1
```

[please click](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/76d9f/3) here so you can see complete sample table and query I tried.

Edite: adding complete table structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (name varchar(50),loca int,locb int)
;

insert into Table1 values ('james',100,2);
insert into Table1 values ('james',100,3);
insert into Table1 values ('james',10,8);
insert into Table1 values ('james',10,8);
insert into Table1 values ('james',10,7);
insert into Table1 values ('james',10,6);
insert into Table1 values ('james',0,7);
insert into Table1 values ('james',10,0);
insert into Table1 values ('james',10);
insert into Table1 values ('james',10);
```

and what I'm looking for is to get (james,108) as that value is repeated two time in entire data, there is repetion of (james,10) but that have null value of loca so Zero value and Null value is to be ignored only those to be considered that have value in both(loca,locb).

Comment: ordering by the same value you partition on doesn't really make sense. Please add the sample data to your question - SQLFiddle isn't really reliable and currently doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hello, thanks I have updated the sample data and also the data..

Comment: `CONCAT(loca,locb)` doesn't make sense. `concat()` is to concatenate string (text) values, not numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH concat AS (
  -- get concat values
    SELECT name,concat(loca,locb) as merged
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE  t1.locb NOTNULL
    AND t1.loca NOTNULL
), concat_count AS (
  -- calculate count for concat values
    SELECT name,merged,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name,merged) as merged_count
    FROM concat
)
SELECT cc.name,cc.merged
FROM concat_count cc
WHERE cc.merged_count = (SELECT max(merged_count) FROM concat_count)
GROUP BY cc.name,cc.merged;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer and time, but when the count of 108 changes like now it's 2 times repeated which can be seen as the dataset is very small and sample but I need to run this in big dataset where I would not know the cc.merged_count = 2... anyway this can be dynamic so it will pick the maximum itself ... that data was sample only to point out what I need...

Comment: @hi4ppl: do you need to find the most appearing combination? please be specific in questions description.

Comment: Hi Dmity, yes exactly most repeating combination... I just give 108 as example sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1f7d8/3)

```
select distinct on (name) *
from (
    select name, loca, locb, count(*) as total
    from Table1
    where loca is not null and locb is not null
    group by 1,2,3
) s
order by name, total desc
```

Comment: Hi Thank, but this sort the records does not select that specific records at the top...

Comment: @hi4ppl You want only the top one? Add `limit 1` to the bottom of the query.

Comment: Hi, this is sample records only when I run in the real dataset it will be million records so if I limit 1 it will pick only one records it wont return 1 record from each name, the gaol is to pick maximum repeat off concat for all names...

Answer (score 0):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/76d9f/16)**

```
select name, 
       newvalue
from (
    select name,
           CONCAT(loca,locb) newvalue,   
           COUNT(CONCAT(loca,locb)) as total,
           row_number() over (order by COUNT(CONCAT(loca,locb)) desc) as att
    from Table1 
    where loca is not null 
      and locb is not null
    GROUP BY name, CONCAT(loca,locb)
) tt
where att=1
```